# BadRequest 400 while trying to call a external API using POST RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate, httpentity

I have to call an external API in Java Spring in which I have to pass a JSON object as follows( XXX and YYY are parameters ).How can I pass this JSON object using the following classes?

```
{
  "codecConfigId": "XXXXXXXX", 
  "inputStreams": [{
    "inputId": "Input_Teste_1024_1",
    "inputPath": "YYYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "selectionMode": "AUTO"
  }]
}
```

What I tried

```
StreamsForCodecs streams = new StreamsForCodecs();
streams.setCodecConfigId(codecConfigId);
streams.setInputStream(path.toString());

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
map.put("x-api-key", "XXXXXXX");
map.put("Accept", "application/json");
```

The `StreamsForCodecs` is a class that has another class linked to that because I need to pass the above JSON, so I created those 2 classes.

```
public class StreamsForCodecs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String codecConfigId;
    ArrayList<InputStreamsCodec> inputStreams = new ArrayList<InputStreamsCodec>();

...
    // Setter Methods

    public void setCodecConfigId(String codecConfigId) {
        this.codecConfigId = codecConfigId;
    }

    public void setInputStream(String path) {
        InputStreamsCodec inputStreamsCodec = new InputStreamsCodec();
        inputStreamsCodec.setInputPath(path);
        inputStreams.add(inputStreamsCodec);
    }

}

class InputStreamsCodec implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String inputPath;
...
Some GetAndSetters

    public void setInputPath(String inputPath) {
        this.inputPath = inputPath;
    }
}
```

I also tried `requestEntity`, `request`, `RestTemplate.postForEntity` and `RestTemplate.exchange`,but in all the scenarios I got the bad request.When I try to call this from POSTman, I didn't get the error.

```
HttpEntity<StreamsForCodecs> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(streams, headers);
request = new HttpEntity(requestEntity, headers);
ResponseEntity<StreamsForCodecsResponse> response= new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, StreamsForCodecsResponse.class);
//ResponseEntity<StreamsForCodecsResponse> response= new //RestTemplate().postForEntity(url, request, StreamsForCodecsResponse.class);
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Here is s part of the stack trace of the exception.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.carlosdv93.controller.CreateStreamsForCodecs.createStreamsForCodecsPOST(CreateStreamsForCodecs.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the correct http headers, you put all the correct headers in the `map` object but never sent it, change your code and populate the `headers` object instead of the `map` nad send it with the request:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.add("x-api-key", "XXXXXXX");
headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
```

Alternatively you can also use the `HttpHeaders` to set the headers:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("x-api-key", "XXXXXXX");
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<StreamsForCodecs> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(streams, headers);
ResponseEntity<StreamsForCodecsResponse> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, StreamsForCodecsResponse.class);
```

Comment: I did what you said, but didn't work.
`MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.add("x-api-key", "XXXXXXX");
headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
`
and send it, continues the 400 BadRequest.

Comment: I edited my comment @Fullstack Guy but is the same bad request error

Comment: @CarlosDv93Dev try using the `HttpHeaders`, the way I showed.

Comment: @ CarlosDv93Dev just check if you have jackson in your classpath

Comment: I did that changes, but still don't work, same error. I have the Jackson core dependency in my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not converting your Object to JSON.

```
    JSONObject requestJson = new JSONObject(streams).toString();
    HttpEntity<StreamsForCodecs> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson , headers);
```

Hope this will help
Use HttpHeaders and HttPEntity as mentioned by fullstack guy